# Why Ext.id function gets overridden?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to wrap a HTMLElement to create a Ext.Element but this *mysteriously* overrides the Ext.id function with some ID and makes ExtJs unusable after that point

I have tried to make this simple example illustrating the problem though I had to dig thru lot of code in original app to find this subtle bug e.g. try this code online http://jsfiddle.net/rdudW/1/ or use this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script> 
<script>
Ext.onReady(function(){
    alert(Ext.id)
    var elem = Ext.Element(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0])
    alert(Ext.id)
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table><table>
</body>
</html>
```

Before calling Ext.Element alert show function definition but after that a id 'ext-gen2'

Note: I know i should be using new Ext.Element but that is not the question, question is why this happens with this simple probable mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've skimmed over the source, and there are a few functons, that if called in wrong scope would override `Ext.id`. The omission of `new` is probably doing just that. One of these functions is called in context of `Ext` object instad of `Element` being created.

See this:

```
Ext.Element = function(element, forceNew){
    var id;
    /* some code here */

    id = dom.id;

    /* some code here */

    /**
     * The DOM element ID
     * @type String
     */
    this.id = id || Ext.id(dom);
};
```

If you call this with `new` then `this` refers to newly created object. If you call this directly, `this` refers to `Ext`

Comment: thanks, i did quick Ext.id search and couldn't find any assignment :)